# Convert matplotlib sliders into webpage

Tags: javascript, python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have made a number of Python scripts that allow the user to explore an equation using matplotlib.widgets such as the Slider and the RadioButtons.

I would like to send these simulations to my colleagues, but they are busy people and running a Python script is an insurmountable hurdle for them. So, I would like to be able to send my program in another format, ideally, as an html page that they could simply open in their browser and still play with the sliders and buttons.

At first, I was very exited to discover projects like [Holoviews](http://ioam.github.io/holoviews/) and [ipywidgets.StaticInteract](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/05/static-interactive-widgets/), which do allow you to embed interactive elements in an iPython notebook. However, these require that every possible plot be pre-generated as an image. So, if I have numerous sliders (I often have 10+ sliders and generate 4+ plots), then the file would quickly become enormous.

[Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#cutomjs-for-widgets) has a nice demonstration of interactive sliders on the web, but the calculations are done by the server, and I do not have my own web server. Bokeh also offers the option of [creating custom Javascript actions](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#cutomjs-for-widgets), which generates an html file which works exactly like I want. However, it seems that I would need to do all of the calculations to update the plot in Javascript, and I do not know Javascript. And, if I did learn Javascript, then it would seem like I could just make the plots and sliders with [d3.js](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/04/using-html-inputs-with-d3js.html).

But do I really need to learn Javascript to do what I want? In short: how can I get make this demo (adapted from the [matplotlib examples page](http://matplotlib.org/users/screenshots.html#slider-demo)) into a webpage that anybody can view?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
a0 = 5; f0 = 3; o0 = 0
s = a0*np.sin(2*np.pi*f0*t + o0)
l, = ax.plot(t,s, lw=2, color='red')
ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(-10,10)

axAmp    = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
axFreq   = plt.axes([0.25, 0.10, 0.65, 0.03])
axOffset = plt.axes([0.25, 0.05, 0.65, 0.03])

sFreq   = Slider(axFreq,   'Freq',   0.1, 30.0, valinit=f0)
sAmp    = Slider(axAmp,    'Amp',    0.1, 10.0, valinit=a0)
sOffset = Slider(axOffset, 'Offset', -10,10,    valinit=o0)

def update(val):
    amp    =    sAmp.val
    freq   =   sFreq.val
    offset = sOffset.val
    l.set_ydata(amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)+offset)
    plt.draw()

sFreq.on_changed(update)
sAmp.on_changed(update)
sOffset.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: use plotly https://plot.ly/. Its one of the easiest solutions to your case. uses d3.js and has nice python api

Comment: To use sliders in plotly, it looks like you still need to do the heavy lifting in javascript: https://plot.ly/python/range-slider/

Comment: Maybe you can mix brython and a js charting library to do what you want. See this [example made using brythonmagic](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/kikocorreoso/brythonmagic/blob/master/notebooks/Highcharts%20%28python%29%20tutorial.ipynb#3d-Charts). This way you don't have to write directly js code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! There are some very beautiful plots in that notebook. It will take me a while to digest all of that information, but at first glance, it seems that a lot of the setup still takes place in javascript. Is this the case, or is it possible to avoid the js?

Comment: @kikocorreoso nice notebooks. btw DanHickstein have you checked [static interactive widgets for ipython](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/05/static-interactive-widgets/) Its pretty old.. may not be relevant with current jupyter notebooks

Comment: @goofd Yes, I found the static interactive widgets (I refer them in my post as "ipywidgets.StaticInteract"), and they basically do what I want, so I was really excited when I started playing with them. However, the catch is that they require that each plot be rendered as an image, so all the client browser does is load the images. This works well for a single slider, but when you have lots of sliders, the number of images that you need becomes astronomical and the file size is huge. Not really workable in my case.

Comment: ohh yes....you are right. well a little bit of d3 is perhaps the easiest then..

Comment: This example does something very similar to what I want to accomplish. http://jsfiddle.net/Murisaki/m1sdtejo/3/